# Antd Upload change data based off file

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, antd

I'm using antd upload, and I would like to change the upload data dynamically depending on the file name. Currently, this works fine for single file uploads, see below:

```
function MyUpload() {
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState();

    return (
        <Upload
            action='...'
            uploadType='...'
            data={{
                fileName: fileName
            }}
            beforeUpload={(file: File, _) => setFileName(file.name)}
            directory={false}
        >
    );
}
```

The problem occurs when I try creating a directory upload field. If I change `directory` to true above, then `beforeUpload` is called several times for each file, but the only `fileName` set is that of the last file processed. Therefore, all the different files will have the upload data of the last file processed.

I was wondering if there was a way to use this approach or perhaps a better approach to set values in the data property that reflect the current file being uploaded, in a dynamic way.

Thanks in advance